# When using visible binding, how do I show a message when nothing should be visible

Tags: knockout.js

Imagine the following scenario.  I have a checkbox that the user can check to filter a  list based on whether they would like to see everyone, or just those persons who are managers.  Here is the simplified code:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="manager-view-toggle" data-bind="checked: onlyViewManagers" />
<ul data-bind="foreach: persons">
    <li data-bind="visible: isManager() || !$parent.onlyViewManagers() , text: name"></li>
</ul>
```

How would I present a message to the user when no persons are visible?  I can't simply do a check on the length of persons as it could well be above 0 but there might be no managers in the list.

I thought about using afterRender but that only fires when the content of the list changes (it seems).

Basically, if no persons were rendered, I would like a little `<li>` that said something like, "No people here bro".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use virtual elements with the foreach binding too:

```
<ul>
    <!-- ko foreach: persons -->
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: persons().length == 0 -->
        <li>No people here</li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
```

You could extend the model so that persons is just the list of people to display, have a look at the [filtering an observable array](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html) example.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I thought of would be this:

```html
<!-- ko if: emptyList(persons()) -->
<ul>
    <li>No people here bro</li>
</ul>
<!-- /ko -->
<ul data-bind="foreach: persons">
    <li data-bind="visible: isManager() || !$parent.onlyViewManagers() , text: name"></li>
</ul>
```

And here is my viewmodel for the above example

```js
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    this.onlyViewManagers = ko.observable(false);

    this.persons = ko.observableArray([]);

    this.emptyList = function(arrayToCheck) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(arrayToCheck, function(item) {
            return item.isManager() || self.onlyViewManagers();
        }) === null
    };
}
```

But this seems counter-intuitive, in addition to repeating the same logic to determine whether to make an item visible or not.

Comment: You could refactor this along the lines of the [filtered view of an observable array](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html) example, then use the same `computed` for the `if` and the `foreach` so that you don't need `visible` data binding on the list items themselves. See also my example in another answer to remove the second `<ul>`.